# Can't run my app; “image not found” referring to bundled framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, runtime-error

I'm trying to include the Sparkle framework in my application. I don't really understand the specific steps necessary, and am now getting this error message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
Referenced from: <..>/build/Debug/CoRay.app/Contents/MacOS/CoRay
Reason: image not found
```

So my question is two part:
1. How do I fix my problem?
2. What is the correct path for including a framework into a Cocoa/Obj-C application?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error is saying that it cannot find a copy of the sparkle framework inside of your app bundle.

You need to add a new Copy Files build phase to your target.  Set it to "Frameworks" to copy frameworks and drag a copy of Sparkle.framework from your Xcode project into the new Copy Files build phase that you have just created.

Comment: This also happens to some of my users. But why does a restart of the app resolves the problem?

Answer (score 22):

After adding Sparkle.framework in "Copy Files" phase, you have to remove it from "Link Binary With Libraries".

Cheers.